# Haskell to Javascript lambda function translation

Tags: javascript, haskell

I have the following lambda function in haskell:

```
cup size = \message -> message size
```

I would like to know what is the equivalent version in JavaScript (for learning purpose), currently I wrote the following version, I would like to if it is correct.

```
const cup = size => (message => message)(size)
```

Comment: Is `message` a method ? Because if yes i do not get the usage of lambda.You could write `cup=message` and in js `cup=str=>message(str)`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian `cup` is not `message`; `cup` is a function that returns a function which applies its argument to `cup`'s argument. One could also write `cup size message = message size`, which makes it more apparent that `cup = flip ($)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your JavaScript code corresponds to

```haskell
cup = \size -> (\message -> message) size
```

in Haskell. Because `\message -> message` is the identity function, this is the same as

```haskell
cup = \size -> size
```

which is the identity function again:

```haskell
cup = id
```

The correct translation would be

```javascript
const cup = size => message => message(size)
```

or

```javascript
function cup(size) { return message => message(size); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your haskell lambda takes an argument and returns a lambda which in turn takes a function as argument and applies that function with the argument given to cup.

In javascript, the equivalent would be this:

```
const cup = size => (message => message(size))
```

You can rewrite it without the parenthesis:

```
const cup = size => message => message(size)
```